# Has anyone also had this status error 255 when running podman?

Tags: macos, containers, podman

Is anyone else having this problem when running podman?

I used normally and now when running
podman machine start
this error appears:

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea6nD.png)

I tried to change the podman configuration and increase the resources but I didn't authorize it;

Comment: Be very careful about what you "wish" for. You are asking "_Is anyone else having this problem_". What do you actually want as an answer? People to chime in and just say "yes"? Ask the question that you _really_ want an answer to. I'd _highly_ suggest you take 5 minutes to read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's going on but here's what I did:

```
➜  ~ podman system connection list
Name                         URI                                                         Identity                                          Default
podman-machine-default       ssh://core@localhost:51014/run/user/501/podman/podman.sock  /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/podman-machine-default  true
podman-machine-default-root  ssh://root@localhost:51014/run/podman/podman.sock           /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/podman-machine-default  false
➜  ~ podman machine rm podman-machine-default

The following files will be deleted:

/Users/xxxxx/.ssh/podman-machine-default
/Users/xxxxx/.ssh/podman-machine-default.pub
/Users/xxxxx/.config/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default.ign
/Users/xxxxx/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default_fedora-coreos-36.20220918.2.2-qemu.x86_64.qcow2
/Users/xxxxx/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/podman-machine-default/podman.sock
/Users/xxxxx/.config/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default.json


Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
➜  ~  podman system connection list
Name        URI         Identity    Default
```

At this point I switched to the Activity Monitor and killed the qemu service. Then I ran the following:

```
➜  ~ podman machine init
Downloading VM image: fedora-coreos-37.20230122.2.0-qemu.x86_64.qcow2.xz: done
Extracting compressed file
Image resized.
Machine init complete
To start your machine run:

podman machine start

➜  ~ podman system connection list
Name                         URI                                                         Identity                                          Default
podman-machine-default       ssh://core@localhost:51014/run/user/501/podman/podman.sock  /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/podman-machine-default  true
podman-machine-default-root  ssh://root@localhost:51014/run/podman/podman.sock           /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/podman-machine-default  false
➜  ~ docker machine start
Starting machine "podman-machine-default"
Waiting for VM ...
Mounting volume... /Users/xxxxx:/Users/xxxxx

This machine is currently configured in rootless mode. If your containers
require root permissions (e.g. ports < 1024), or if you run into compatibility
issues with non-podman clients, you can switch using the following command:

podman machine set --rootful

API forwarding listening on: /var/run/docker.sock
Docker API clients default to this address. You do not need to set DOCKER_HOST.

Machine "podman-machine-default" started successfully
```

Hope this helps.